# Help with composing an $\epsilon-N$ proof of mine

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

I need to prove $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{4n+3}{3n-1}=\frac{4}{3}$ using the definition we all know. I want to share my attempt as the semester didn't start yet so I'm not sure my proof is valid.
First I write

$\left | \frac{4n+3}{3n-1}-\frac{4}{3} \right |=\left | \frac{13}{3(3n-1)} \right |\leq \left |\frac{13}{9n}  \right |$

Now I want to claim that for all $\epsilon>0$, choosing $N=\left \lceil \frac{13}{9\epsilon} \right \rceil $ gives what we need, but how do I justify it? I thought showing the following:
for all $n>N$,

$n>\frac{13}{9\epsilon}\Rightarrow \epsilon >\frac{13}{9n}= \left |\frac{13}{9n}  \right | \geq  \left | \frac{4n+3}{3n-1}-\frac{4}{3} \right |$

but it feels so uneeded, could I have just stopped the proof after showing $N$, and claiming it satisfies $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$?

Comment: Note that $$\frac{13}{9n}< \frac2n, $$ so choosing $N>\frac2\varepsilon$ we conclude.

Comment: Thanks for slightly improving my proof, yet this didn't answer my question at all.

Comment: Your first inequality $\left | \frac{13}{3(3n-1)} \right |\leq \left |\frac{13}{9n}  \right |$ is backwards.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost correct (see LutzL's remark). 
We can even say that for $n\geq 2$:
$$\left | \frac{4n+3}{3n-1}-\frac{4}{3} \right |=\left | \frac{13}{3(3n-1)} \right |<\frac{2}{n}.$$
So given $\varepsilon>0$, for all $n> \max(2/\varepsilon,2)$, we have that $n\geq 2$, $2/n<\varepsilon$,  and 
$$\left | \frac{4n+3}{3n-1}-\frac{4}{3} \right |<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: No, it is not correct. $\frac1{3n-1}>\frac1{3n}$. Either $\frac1{2n}$ or $\frac1{3(n-1)}$ are upper bounds.

Comment: @LutzL You are right. Thanks for pointing out.